# django-tastypie: how to add custom commands

Tags: django, command, tastypie

I know how to add custom commands for django projects. But when I use tastypie, the way to add custom commands just doesn't work. My currently file layout looks like below:

```
api/
    __init__.py
    manage.py
    api/
    models/
    resources/
    management/
        __init__.py
        commands/
            __init__.py
            createapikey.py
```

I don't know where should I put the management directory. In fact, I have already tried to put  the whole management directory in up-level directory and inside the `api/api/` folder. Neither way works.

Comment: tastypie shouldn't affect your project structure. Tastypie is just an app that helps defining an API but everything works the same at the django level.

Comment: @FacundoOlano You are right. Tastypie shouldn't affect my project structure. In my project, the folder api is the project's name and there is no app in my project. That's why the custom commands doesn't. I solved this problem by **create an empty app** and put the management directory into the app folder. Thanks for your point.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210690/how-to-do-a-project-wide-custom-django-admin-command), since my project has no app in it, there is no way to put the management directory. So the solution is just create a **core** app and put the management directory into that core app. Problem solved : )